# How do you read strings from a data register using pymodbus?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, plc, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I'm trying to use my raspberry pi as a client for modbus communication between it and a S7-1200 Siemens plc. I got it to read integers from holding register, but not strings. When I try to search for a solution online on how to read strings from the plc holding register nothing useful comes up. I tried a program online that is supposed to be able to do it but I just keep getting an error every time I run it. Can anyone help? I have the code for the program and the error message below.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.compat import iteritems

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = ModbusClient("192.168.0.1", port=502, auto_open=True)
    client.connect()
    result  = client.read_holding_registers(1, 1, unit=1)
    print("Result : ",result)
    decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)

    decoded = {
        'name': decoder.decode_string(10).decode(),
    }



    for name, value in iteritems(decoded):
        print ("%s\t" % name, value)
    client.close()
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYIs2.png)

[Data Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HijmH.png)

[PLC MB Server Block Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOFjz.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can't take strings value from modbus communication

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to read stored information from a register from input from a HMI like the name of someplace or something, and have it read by the raspberry pi. Or is it that you can't take string values using modbus period.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for example you want to read speed of a asynchronous motor and you use a driver. You have a raspberry pi. You use python and Modbus TCP Protocol .

speed of motor is registered 40001.

result  = client.read_holding_registers(1, 1, unit=1) you can read just 40001 adress.

result = client.read_input_registers(0x01,1, unit=0x01) you can read just 30001 adress.

Answer (score 0):

### Your Decoding is fine.

> It's your setup & request that's the issue.
> PLC Setup looks wrong.
> You are also only requesting 1 register to read.
> Your request is not getting any response (including error).

- Coke = b'436f6b65' = [17263, 27493]
- Pizza = b'50697a7a6100' = [20585, 31354, 24832]
- Cookies = b'436f6f6b69657300' = [17263, 28523, 26981, 29440]

Pad out with 0's to keep register lengths the same.
Store in plc Modbus registers that can be read.

- Coke = b'436f6b6500000000' = [17263, 27493, 0, 0]
- Pizza = b'50697a7a61000000' = [20585, 31354, 24832, 0]
- Cookies = b'436f6f6b69657300' = [17263, 28523, 26981, 29440]

Request 4 registers per word and decode.

Comment: I think its worth noting that this is not something the [Modbus spec](https://www.modbus.org/specs.php) covers. Registers are 16 bit values so you can store ASCII characters in these in a number of ways (one per register or two combined big/little endian etc).